# How to check for file system consistency after power outage

Tags: filesystems, fsck, e2fsck, smartmontools

What can I do to check if a file system (data in files and the hardware) is intact or corrupt after a computer is shutdown abruptly due to power outage?

My home desktop computer was shut down by sudden power outage. The computer automatically rebooted itself after the power is back, and I then shut it down manually in the regular way. The computer runs Ubuntu 18.10, Linux 4.18.0. It has a SSD and a HDD, where the SSD holds the boot, root, and all the essential partitions, and the HDD holds one partition for data files. I think all the file systems are `ext4`. I want to determine if there was a corruption in any file, and if the SSD or HDD had a physical damage.

I think I can use `smartmontools` to check the physical damage.
I am lacking a clue about how to check the data integrity. It looks that `fsck` can do some checks on the file system, but it looks I need to unmount the partition to inspect. How can I run `fsck` to inspect the SSD? Can I use a USB boot stick which has Ubuntu on it?

I would appreciate any pointers.

---

**Edit**

The 'duplicate question' link nominally answered my question, and I am closing this question.

Among the several methods suggested in the link and the comments to this question, what I actually did is the following.

I booted the computer, and ran

`$ sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda4`

where `/dev/sda4` is the SSD. Then, I rebooted. The system started up, showed something about the disk check for a few seconds, and presented the normal log-in screen.

I also did

`$ sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdb1`

for the HDD. Upon reboot, the start up screen showed a progress for about a minute, and then the normal log-in screen came up. 
I'm not really sure if there was no error, if a problem was fixed silently, or if there was an error, but I assume the lack of explicit warning indicates that there was no error.

Thank you for the comments and the link.

Comment: You answered your own question: "*Can I use a USB boot stick which has Ubuntu on it?*" - yes.

Comment: If you’re running Ubuntu, you don’t even need a USB stick, there’s an entry in the boot menu to run in recovery mode with `fsck`.

Comment: If power-off caused physical damage, then get your money back. That should never never ever happen. (It may have happened in the 1980s, but not since auto parking)

Comment: If journalling is enabled, then there will be no corruption.What are the settings in `/etc/fstab`? (However unsaved files will be unsaved)